# Bootstrap carousel TypeError: $next[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, typeerror

I built a bootstrap carousel on a Laravel 5.5 Website, using Vue2. Everything worked fine, but now, all of a sudden, the slides don't slide properly and the console is throwing the following TypeError:

> TypeError: $next[0] is undefined

Sliding back is fine, but when sliding to the right (i.e. next slide), the carousel shows some white space or is jumping directly to the next slide without sliding. 
I am importing bootstrap via CDN. This is what my carousel looks like (including Vue directives):

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <figure v-for="(pic, index) in pics" :class="(pic_key === index) ? 'carousel-item active' : 'carousel-item'">
                <img class="d-block w-100" :src="pic" alt="">
            </figure>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

And this is my Vue file (app.js):

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.filters = require('vue2-filters');
window.Event = new Vue();

Vue.component('location_map', require('./components/HomeMaps.vue'));

Vue.component('modal', {
    props: ['pic_key', 'pics', 'showGalleryModal'],
    template: `
        <div class="modal is-active">
            <div class="modal-background"></div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
            <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close" @click="$emit('close')"></button>
        </div>
    `
});

Vue.use(filters);

new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data() {
        return {
            showGalleryModal: false,
            pic_key: 0,
            pics: [],
        }
    }
});
```

As you might have noticed, there's another single file component doing some stuff on another page of the website. The error occured after I implemented this other component, but I don't see why it should influence the carousel, since it has nothing to do with it (it doesn't even use bootstrap at all)...

However, is there anyone with an idea how to fix this? Is there a chance that this is just a bootstrap bug?

Answer (score 2):

That just happened to me. I realized the error `$next[0] is undefined` is thrown because I am using Bootstrap 3, not 4.

With Bootstrap 3 the class of the element containing the pictures should be `item` and not `carousel-item`

So, if it is your case, just change this line:

```
<figure v-for="(pic, index) in pics" :class="(pic_key === index) ? 'carousel-item active' : 'carousel-item'">
```

to this:

```
<figure v-for="(pic, index) in pics" :class="(pic_key === index) ? 'item active' : 'item'">
```